# Loading WinForms on other threads

Tags: c#-4.0

Like many others, I need to open WinForms on other threads. After reading a lot of different articles, I see that it is not possible but my question is will it be possible at a time or is there a way to achieve the following goal?

I'm creating an application with a lot of tool windows that are long to initialize (because of many controls or other things that cannot be put on worker threads) and these tools windows are not needed immediately when the main application starts but I still want to show them when they'll be ready to be used.

Is this possible to achieve in some way without needing a feature, WinForms on other threads, that seams to be currently impossible now?

thanks in advance

EDIT

All of you, thanks for the good articles and hints but it was my error to not provide any more details about one of my real nead. I'm currently using a third party control that enables me to open WinForms in an MDI container as tabbed windows (i'm using Telerik.WinControls.UI.Docking.RadDock). For this, the Main UI thread, the one that host the RadDock, needs to be informed of newly added Winforms to be able to add them to is "tabbed" window list. This is one of the thing that I do not see how it can be done because this will involve that one of my tool window, created on another thread, can be marshalled and be used on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not that you need to show your WinForms on other threads, rather, you need to make the work inside those forms asynchronous and implement proper thread-safe synchronization. I have two blog articles that apply to just this.

- [Using ISynchronizeInvoke to update your UI safely from another thread](http://danderson.io/posts/using-isynchronizeinvoke-to-update-your-ui-safely-from-another-thread/)
- [Writing thread-safe event handlers with the Task Parallel Library](http://danderson.io/posts/writing-thread-safe-event-handlers-with-the-task-parallel-library-in-net-4-0/) (includes source code)

Both are for Windows Forms, and there are tons of articles you can find on making your WinForms asynchronous.

A for instance.

```
ToolWindowForm form = new ToolWindowForm()) {
form.Show();
// other code
```

Let's say you have this somewhere in your code where you need this tool window to display, but it takes such a long time to load it blocks the rest of your code from execution. Well, showing the form on another thread could be one way to accomplish this, and is very much so possible. What can make this exceedingly complex though is that if you are communicating between forms and need access to controls, you are going to run into CrossThreadViolations and IllegalCrossThreadCalls. Its easier and safer just to make the work behind each form asynchronous.

**Edit**
If its a must you can add private members to store instances to the forms, ie.

```
private Form m_MyToolForm = new Form();
private Form m_MyToolForm2 = new Form();
```

Then somewhere in code.

```
public void ShowToolForm() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowToolFormAsync));
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}  

private void ShowToolFormAsync() {
    m_MyToolForm.ShowDialog(); // Blocks on this thread
}
```

You can also use the Task Parallel Library if you are on .NET 4.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => m_MyToolForm.ShowDialog());
```

Comment: Thanks David, but imagine the following scenario: I have an MDI Form that needs to load 10 child forms that contains a lot of complex controls in them that takes times to load. What I want to do is load these forms on another thread and still be able to add them as MDI child form. Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow and it seems that I can put long comment so I'll put them one after the other.

Comment: David, thanks again for taking time to respond to my question, all of the informations that you are providing are really relevant to the task that I want to achieve and helping me a lot in making lights on this but... my problem is not with the data required in my forms but instead with the time it takes to "constructs" the form with all of there controls (tab controls, grids, charts, etc.). I'm probably missing something about your examples because I do not see how I can load Forms on another thread (and it is the purpose of my question) without encountering some threading issues.

Comment: The loading portion of my Form's data are already done on background thread in an efficient way but I need more, I need to load the controls (i.e. my Forms) on other threads. I want to load a form on the background and when loading is finished, add it to the main form's thread to be able to have my forms act as mdi child forms. Sorry if your answer already answered it, I just can't understand how it is possible with your sample.

Comment: As an example of what I don't want (sorry Visual Studio .NET 2010 team even if your product is a must), Visual Studio .NET 2010 opens or loads a lot of things that probably explains why it is so slow to open (even if the splash screen is disabled).  This is what I do not want. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: There's not a way to load the UI controls on another thread (at least for what you want). They must be part of the UI thread to ensure they get their window messages processed for things like events and painting and handle creation. All you can do is make sure that any heavy bound operations are loaded no another thread, but not the actual control itself. If you are using WinForms it doesn't handle well with a lot of controls (especially user controls), but this is something that was fixed in WPF.

Comment: Thanks david, this was my understanding, without having any links explicitly saying that WPF does it (except remembering reading something about it). I go on the WPF path with this new requirement: Is it possible to convert my WinForms project to a class library, using WindowsFormHost control to host my WinForms form in a WPF application and being able to load my winforms on other thread? If not possible to use my winforms as is, if I convert them to usercontrols, will this be possible?

Comment: That would be its own subject for another question, plus I've not dived deep into WPF enough to be able to answer that accurately for you. I know you can host your WinForms stuff in WPF and visa-versa, but as far as what more you can do with WPF I cannot answer that quite yet.

Comment: Thanks David, I created another post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370105/loading-winforms-hosted-by-windowsformhost-in-background-thread-in-wpf

Comment: Links in the answer are no longer available, could you provide new?

Answer (score 0):

I dont seem how this would not be possible.
The only big problem with creating forms and updating form controls over different threads,
is that you will need a thread-safe callback otherwise you will get errors that only the parent thread who created the form is able to update a gui.

More information about this thread-safe callback and the InvokeRequired stuff which is required with this cross-threading is found at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: This is exactly the problem that I have because if I'm creating form on other threads, how can they be brought back to the main form's thread acting has MDI child forms.